# combine two if conditions results in one if condition

Tags: php, logical-operators, strstr

if condition 1  :

```
if(isset($_POST['searchOrder']) && $_POST['searchOrder']!='')
   {
       $userToSearch = "WHERE name='Conformed'"; 

   }
```

If condition 2 :

```
if(strstr($status, "value1") !== false ) 

    {
    $hide .= 'style="display: none;"';
    }
```

i need `if condition 1 OR If condition 2` , i tried below :

```
if (((strstr($status, "value1") !== false) ||  
   isset($_POST['searchOrder']) && $_POST['searchOrder']!='')
   {
       $userToSearch = "WHERE name='Conformed'";        
   })
                  {
                     $hide .= 'style="display: none;"';              
                  }
```

I also tried below , but both gave error....

```
if ((strstr($status, "value1") !== false) ||  isset($_POST['searchOrder']) && $_POST['searchOrder']!=''))
                  {
                     $userToSearch = "WHERE name='Conformed'";   
                     $hide .= 'style="display: none;"';              
                  }
```

Comment: so you want both conditions should be passed ? or any one ?

Comment: @prakashtank i want 1st if condition result and 2nd if condition result in `one if condition`.....

Comment: for first one use `!empty($_POST['searchOrder'])` instead of `isset` and `!=""`

Comment: @vickey : please check my answer if you want to combine  both condition

Comment: It's not clear, you want this :  `if ( (condition1) || (condition2) ) {result 1; result 2;}` ?

Comment: @MickaelLeger you are right....

Comment: And it doesn't works if you write it as I do (with the parenthesis around each condition)? And you can write `if (!empty($_POST['searchOrder'])` for your condition 1, empty test if isset + not empty (so not null, not "", etc. Look some doc :)

Comment: @MickaelLeger okay, thanks , i will try , please post an answer with code....

Comment: You already have a lot of anwser :) But I don't get the logic of you code because if you want `if ( (condition1) || (condition2) ) {result 1; result 2;}` you can have `$userToSearch = "WHERE name='Conformed'";` even with `empty($_POST['searchOrder']` because it's a "OR" condition. Maybe you want `condition1 && condition2`, no? But you will have the two result ONLY if BOTH are respected. If the result1 and result2 depend of ONE condition each, why do you want to make ONE condition for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so you might want to rearrange your conditions, or put parentheses around the second group. Then just write the second part in the same block, like this.

```
if (strstr($status, "value1") !== false || (isset($_POST['searchOrder']) && $_POST['searchOrder']!=''))
{
    $userToSearch = "WHERE name='Conformed'";
    $hide .= 'style="display: none;"';       
}
```

Comment: 1st condition : i want to display rows where `name='Conformed'";` but they are not displaying, but only 2nd condition is working `$hide .= 'style="display: none;"';  `

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: i am getting result for this : `$hide .= 'style="display: none;"';  ` , but not for `$userToSearch = "WHERE name='Conformed'";`

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to say. If you `echo $userToSearch` after the `if`, does it echo? From that point on, I don't know what you're doing with that variable, so I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: okay, i will tell cleary, there is one row in table which have `name` column with value = `Confirmed` , that row is not displaying.....

Comment: yes , once i done `echo $userToSearch` it displayed result : `ORDER DATE WHERE name='Conformed' WHERE name='Conformed' WHERE name='Conformed' WHERE name='Conformed' WHERE name='Conformed' WHERE name='Conformed' WHERE name='Conformed' WHERE name='Conformed' WHERE name='Conformed'`

Comment: Then it worked, wouldn't you agree? But at that point I don't know what you do with `$userToSearch` (I suppose you're appending it to some query), and it is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165496/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-federico-klez-culloca).

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
if((isset($_POST['searchOrder']) && $_POST['searchOrder']!='') || strstr($status, "value1") !== false) {
       $userToSearch = "WHERE name='Conformed'"; 
       $hide .= 'style="display: none;"';
   }
```

Comment: `||` means either one of the two condition should be satisfy ? if OP wants both then this code might not work

Comment: @prakashtank in some comments (and in the question itself) is explicit asket for `(condition1 OR condition2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to satisfy both conditions then do something like this :

```
if (((strstr($status, "value1") !== false)) &&  (isset($_POST['searchOrder']) && $_POST['searchOrder']!='')))
                  {
                     $userToSearch = "WHERE name='Conformed'";   
                     $hide .= 'style="display: none;"';              
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want two conditions alternatively you should remember about grouping.

`(condition1) || (condition2)`

In your case you've got && condition as part of second case, it is not grouped so it is processing first your OR condition between condition1 and first part of condition2, than last AND which is not you wanted.